# Google Chrome Left / Right navigational arrows - always showing

Tags: google-chrome, navigation

When using Google Chrome on OSX, swiping left or right you'll see a circle with an arrow in either corner, indicating going back and forward in your history, see here:

http://cld.jxpr.se/image/1Z3D1R3K141B

On a site I am developing, I have these arrows always present, multiply stacked on top of each other, see here:

http://cld.jxpr.se/image/2o0N2O1d2e0t

That is in the middle of the page, at full screen. These arrow only show when the browser window is expanded beyond the max site width.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 3):

I get the same problem. I'm working on a 27" imac so it might affect me more than most people. i normally just create a new tab and copy paste my url into it. i then close the old tab. not a long term fix though :(